# I am trying to get data from php $_GET then parse it using rest api, but it causes an error

Tags: php, json, rest, curl, parse-platform

I am trying to get data from php $_GET then parse it using rest api, but it causes an error,so plz anybody help..

```
<?php  
$number=$_GET['name'];
$media=$_GET['media'];

$url = 'https://api.parse.com/1/classes/AppTo';  
$appId = 'ccccc';  
$restKey = 'ccccc';  
$headers = array(  
"Content-Type: application/json",  
"X-Parse-Application-Id: " . $appId,  
"X-Parse-REST-API-Key: " . $restKey  
);  

$objectData = '{"name":(json_encode($number)), "age":(json_encode($media))}';  
$rest = curl_init();  

curl_setopt($rest,CURLOPT_URL,$url);  
curl_setopt($rest,CURLOPT_POST,1);  
curl_setopt($rest,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$objectData);  
curl_setopt($rest,CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,$headers);  
curl_setopt($rest,CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);  
curl_setopt($rest,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);  
$response = curl_exec($rest);  
echo $response;  
print_r($response);  
curl_close($rest);  
?>
```

Comment: You should show us the error

Comment: {"code":107,"error":"invalid json: {\"name\":(json_encode($number)), \"age\":(json_encode($media))}"}{"code":107,"error":"invalid json: {\"name\":(json_encode($number)), \"age\":(json_encode($media))}"}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are literally posting the text `{"name":(json_encode($number)), "age":(json_encode($media))}`. You can construct your json like this instead:

```
$objectData = json_encode(array('name' => $number, 'age' => $media));
```

Answer (score 1):

You are posting wrong data change

`$objectData = '{"name":(json_encode($number)), "age":(json_encode($media))}';`

to

`$objectData = json_encode(array('name' => $number, 'age' => $media));`